# How do I solve this error: "SQL error: too many arguments"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, mysql-x-devapi

I have an API through Firebase Functions. When sending an request to the API with the body *{"name":"1234"}* with postman. I get the error 401 "*SQL : Error: Too many arguments*"

This is my function:
*index.js*

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const mysqlx = require("@mysql/xdevapi");

exports.getUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  functions.logger.info("name: ", name);
  functions.logger.info("name type: ", typeof name);

  try {
    const session = await mysqlx.getSession({
      user: "user",
      password: "secretpassword",
      host: "hostname",
      schema: "database",
      port: 33060,
    });

    session.sql("USE database").execute().then(() => {
      const sql = "SELECT * FROM database.users WHERE user_name = ?";
      session.sql(sql).bind(1, name).execute()
          .then((result) => {
            res.status(200).send("User gathered: " + result);
          }).catch((err) => {
            functions.logger.info("sql statement: ", sql);
            functions.logger.error("err: ", err);
            res.status(401).send("SQL : " + err);
          });
    }).catch((err) => {
      functions.logger.error("err: ", err);
      res.status(402).send("Session Error:" + err);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error("error: ", error);
    res.status(500)
        .send("An error occurred while fetching data from the database: " + error);
  }
});
```

I have tried binding the variable by setting `user_name` to both `user_name = ?` and `user_name = :name`. Setting `user_name` to `?` when trying to bind resulted in a timeout in all cases except the one in my included codeblock. Setting `user_name` to `:name` resulted in all cases in the error specified in my question. I've tried binding using all these methods:

1. `.bind("name": name)`
2. `.bind(name)`
3. `.bind([name])`

My expected result is a response of the row where the user_name column matches the input name. From there I plan to extract data from the user row, of which code I have not included.

I have multiple loggers throughout the code, these are the logged values:

1. `functions.logger.info("name: ", name);` logs: `name: 1234`
2. `functions.logger.info("name type: ", typeof name);` logs: `name type: string`
3. `functions.logger.info("sql statement: ", sql);` logs:
   `sql statement: SELECT * FROM database.users WHERE user_name = ?`
4. `functions.logger.error("err: ", err);` logs:

```
err:  Error: Too many arguments
    at SqlResultHandler.BaseHandler.<computed> (/workspace/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/Protocol/InboundHandlers/BaseHandler.js:121:17)
    at Array.entry (/workspace/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/Protocol/InboundHandlers/BaseHandler.js:92:29)
    at WorkQueue.process (/workspace/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/WorkQueue.js:77:19)
    at Client.handleServerMessage (/workspace/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/Protocol/Client.js:169:21)
    at Client.handleNetworkFragment (/workspace/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/Protocol/Client.js:213:14)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Connection.js:800:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9) {
  info: {
    severity: 0,
    code: 5015,
    sqlState: 'HY000',
    msg: 'Too many arguments'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of arguments exceeds the number of placeholders in the SQL statement. In your case, the statement specifies one placeholder and you
provide two arguments via `bind(1, name)`.

As described in the X DevAPI [user guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/parameter-binding.html), named placeholders are
supported only for CRUD statements, whereas SQL statements only support ordinary placeholders, so, in this case, both `bind(name)` and `bind([name])` should
work.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI connector for Node.js

Comment: Turns out all I had to do was wait one day and suddenly, what I had tried multiple times, worked! Using both `bind(name)` and `bind([name])` works, whereas before I just got timed out, which suggests it was some network error all along, thanks for the help!